# Run action every minute sharp using kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin, timer, kotlin-coroutines, delay, coroutine

I believe this can be done, just don't know that is the best API to easily achieve this...

Basically, I have the following method:

```
private val tickerPeriod = 1.minutes

private suspend fun saveCachedValuesPeriodically() {
        delay(getInitialDelay())
        while (currentCoroutineContext().isActive) {
            saveCachedValues()
            delay(tickerPeriod)
        }
}
```

I want to run the method `saveCachedValues()` every minute with precision to the second, using kotlin coroutines. So, if the first timestamp happens with 0 seconds all the following should also be like that.

But what is happening with the code above is that, due to the time spent on `savedCachedValues()`, the milliseconds will increase at every iteration, and after some iterations, the seconds part will also be different...

What would be a nice way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer from @Jorn as a basis, I ended up with the following solution to address my comment in his response.

```
private lateinit var nextRun: ZonedDateTime
private suspend fun saveCachedValuesPeriodically() {
    delay(getInitialDelay())
    while (currentCoroutineContext().isActive) {
        val now = dateTimeProvider.getCurrentZonedDateTimeUTC()
        nextRun= now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
            .plus(tickerPeriod.toJavaDuration())
        saveCachedValues()
        delay(java.time.Duration.between(now, nextRun).toKotlinDuration())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of saving the delay period, save the next execution time and calculate how long to delay until the next call:

```
private val tickerPeriod = 1.minutes
private lateinit var nextRun: Instant

private suspend fun saveCachedValuesPeriodically() {
        delay(getInitialDelay())
        while (true) {
            nextRun = Instant.now().plus(tickerPeriod.toJavaDuration())
            saveCachedValues()
            delay(Duration.between(Instant.now(), nextRun).toKotlinDuration())
        }
}
```

You may need to account for the case where the `saveCachedValues()` call takes longer than `tickerPeriod`.

Too bad there's no `kotlin.time.Instant` to work with `kotlin.time.Duration`...

Comment: The simpler `while(true)` would be fine here because there’s a `delay()` call inside the loop.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'll change that. Just copied it from the question initially.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! However, it still increases a bit every iteration (even if less). Since this is supposed to run over a long time, it might affect after some time...

Comment: @amp Then change the calculation so that it doesn't. For example, by saving the actual start time and then only adding increments of the `tickerPeriod`.

Comment: @Jorn I will try it out next week. I just thought there was some sort of API (with coroutines/flows) that I was not aware, that was able to do this. Thanks anyways! :)